# Typo3: Subpages as Onepager

Tags: typo3

I want all subpages of my Typo3 site to show as a onepager.

I have the following structure in my Typo3 Backend:

- Rootpage

  - Home
  - Portfolio
  - Kundinnen
  - Presse
  - Kontakt

My problem is, that the Portfolio and Presse sites have different backend layouts then the rest.

The Code for my Sitepackage is here: https://github.com/lisagoetz/site_annaschunck

I now only get the content of colpos = 0.
My Default backend layout has 1 Column, Portfolio backend layout has 4 columns and Presse backend layout 2 columns.

Code in my setup.typoscript:

```
lib.content = COA
lib.content {

    ### Content from Homepage
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            pidInList.data = site.rootPageId
            orderBy = sorting
            where.cObject = COA
            where.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    field = colPos
                    intval = 1
                    ifEmpty = 0
                    noTrimWrap = | AND colPos=||
                }
            }
        }
        stdWrap {
            if.isLessThan.field = doktype
            if.value = 3
            wrap = <section id="p{field:uid}">|</section>
            wrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }
    ### Contents from subpages
    30 = CONTENT
    30 {
        table = pages
        select.orderBy = sorting
        select.where = doktype != 199

        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            10 = CONTENT
            10 {
                table = tt_content
                select {
                    pidInList.field = uid
                    orderBy = sorting
                    where.cObject = COA
                    where.cObject {
                        10 = TEXT
                        10 {
                            field = colPos
                            intval = 1
                            ifEmpty = 0
                            noTrimWrap = | AND colPos=||
                        }
                    }
                }
                stdWrap < lib.content.10.stdWrap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Code in my Template:

```
<html data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true" xmlns:f="https://xsd.helhum.io/ns/typo3/cms-fluid/master/ViewHelpers">
    <!-- Nutzen des Layouts "Page/Standard" -->
    <f:layout name="Page/Standard"/>

    <!-- Rendern des Hauptinhalt -->
    <f:section name="Main">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content"/>
    </f:section>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hello @LisaG, unfortunately I think we need to take a look on your code before we can find the problem's source.

Comment: I added the link to my code on github.

Comment: You could load the tt_content of defined set of pages and tables via typoscript. Or write a ViewHelper to do it with PHP.

Comment: @Jack70 Do you have a code example how to solve it with typoscript? I don't have any experience with writing ViewHelpers or PHP.

Comment: @LisaG Did you read the tutorial Typoscript in 45 minutes? There is an example "Reading content records". Now if you check out the tsref, you might find more examples of select. And how to write conditions, if needed. Try something first and post the code, then we can help further.

Comment: @Jack70 I added the code I tried the last two days but now I'm stuck again.